Unreal 5 Pixel Streaming Audio Not Working in Browser
I’m encountering an issue with Pixel Streaming in Unreal Engine 5 where everything works as expected except for the audio. Here’s my setup:

I run the .exe file with these arguments: -AudioMixer -PixelStreamingIP=localhost -PixelStreamingPort=8888.
I run the Pixel Streaming web server from the official GitHub repository.
The .exe running on the server has audio, and I’ve tested both audio from Blueprints and in-scene audio (importing audio in the Content Browser and adding them to the scene), but once I connect through the browser, there’s no audio at all.

I’ve tried multiple virtual audio solutions like VB-Cable, VoiceMeeter, and others, but none seem to fix the issue. The game runs perfectly in the browser on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but the audio just won’t play, both local and from remote access.
I am using a temporary workaround, but it’s not ideal.
I added the PixelStreamingAudioComponent to the scene and set the browser (where Unreal + Pixel Streaming are running on the remote server) to use VB-Cable Output as the microphone and open the stream link (127.0.0.1). This allows the browser to capture everything from the system’s audio output and sends it to the PixelStreaming server.
To prevent a feedback loop, I disabled audio for the browser, Unreal, and Cable Output in the Audio Mixer.
This is a hacky solution, and a more native fix would be preferable, but I haven’t found one yet.
How to fix this problem?

Unreal version is 5.3.2
Pixel Streaming version is the latest from the Github repository (branch 5.3)
OS where Pixel Streaming runs is Windows 10

